# Adjust two horizontal lists

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a footer nav menu which should look like two horizontal lists.

```
<div class="nav-bottom">
<ul id="top-bnav">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="bottom-bnav">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Right now my css looks like this

```
.nav-bottom {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 555px;
margin-top: 80px;
}

.nav-bottom ul {
height: 18px;
width: 555px;
display: block;
}

.nav-bottom ul li {
display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}

.nav-bottom a{
display: inline-block;
color: #cc7a87;
margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Now it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Seasamh/48aMJ/

What I need is to make width of bottom "li" to adjust the width of the top "li", so that link in the bottom would be exactly the same width as at the top. Can I do it without using "display: table"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem was that the length of the each link is different, so defining general width may be tricky. Right now I'm using temporary solution, I defined margin-right to "li" in the top list so that they match the bottom list. Defining "min-width" also works, but as far as the longest link is 130px, this crashes layout as menu appears to be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all write the text for all li. Then take the width of whichever li is the max. wide.
Assign that width to `.nav-bottom ul li`.

Do not use `min-width` or `max-width` just use `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `min-width: 50px;` on `li`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48aMJ/2/)

```
  .nav-bottom ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the width on a tag.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48aMJ/3/)

```
.nav-bottom a{
display: inline-block;
color: #cc7a87;
margin-left: 8px;
width: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be define width for  `.nav-bottom ul li`. Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/T6U5s/)